# Sub-method's finally{..} is performed before calling parent method's catch()

Tags: java

I have an outer method that tries and catches exceptions coming from an inner method,

```
try {
   process();
} catch (Exception e) {
  //...
}
```

The inner method `throws Exception` to the parent, but also has a `finally{..}` because it needs to close some connections. It does not have a `catch` block itself.

```
    public void process() throws Exception {
        try {
           // Open connections, etc.
        }
        finally {  
           // Method has no catch() but a finally{..} is required to close connections
           if (ftpConn != null) {
               ftpConn.close();
           }
           // etc.
        }
    }
```

I see in the debugger that if `process()` has an exception, its `finally` is executed **first** before getting to the outer caller's `catch`. This is counterintuitive to me because I expected the outer caller's `catch()` to be executed first, and then the inner method's `finally`. Just wanted to verify why this happens. In a regular try/catch/finally sequence, `catch` always happens first, and `finally` last.

Comment: Because `finally` blocks **must** evaluate after their associated `try`s; regardless of exceptions - and no, it can't jump back to an enclosed `try` to do so, it's always in the local call stack. Here it should probably be using a `try-with-Resources`.

Comment: By design. Why do you expect that the outer `catch` block is executed first and then goes back into the inner code block (it just left) to call its `finally` block?

Comment: Yes, that's what I expect. A "finally" is something that's *final* . I was always taught it happens at the very end, regardless of what comes before.

Comment: Correct. In my understanding a `finally` is something that's final and should execute after the appropriate catch handler.

Comment: yes, it is final in the called method, not in the calling method (since it is declared in the called method and not in the calling one) - also consider that the method chain can be much longer, varios methods being called,  and some `catch` block could (in your scenario) destroy (release resources, close connections, closing GUI, ....) something needed in the `finally` block of the called method

Answer (score 3):

This makes sense because of how `finally` blocks are determined to be executed [by the language standard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2).  For your example, this also happens in two separate calls, so semantics are typically `try-catch-finally` in each frame in the call stack.

The most relevant parts are here:

> A try statement with a finally block is executed by first executing
> the try block. Then there is a choice:
>
> - If execution of the try block completes normally, then the finally block is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes normally.
>   - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S.
>
> ... (There's a part here about if the try block completes abnormally because you intentionally declared a `throw`, but that's not needed for this discussion.)
>
> - If execution of the try block completes abruptly for any other reason R, then the finally block is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason R.
>   - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and reason R is discarded).

In **all** cases, the `finally` block is executed after the `try` block for which it is declared after.

This also means if your `finally` block encounters an exception, it will bubble up the exception through the call chain to a suitable `catch` block (or all the way up if no such `catch` exists).

To bring the example closer, the big thing to note is that your calls are as follows:

- try

  - try
  - finally
- catch

Your nested try-finally statement will always conclude - either normally or abruptly for any given reason - before any exception is bubbled back to the previous call in the stack.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. On exceptions, It's the `catch` block that is executed after the `try` block, not `finally`, isn't it? Even if you had a regular `try/catch/finally` sequence, and there was an exception, the flow wouldn't go to `finally` immediately, it would go to `catch`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @geneb.:  That's because everything happens in the same frame in the call stack.  First sequence - bang, try-catch-finally gets executed in that order.  In a nested call, you have a try that calls out to something else that has a try-finally, and then the try-finally either do or don't complete successfully - well, the `finally` still must fire.  Maybe the relevant parts I omitted from the spec for brevity are relevant after all...

Comment: It's "the `catch` block that *belongs to the `try`*" which is executed before `finally`. The called function doesn't even know whether the caller has a `catch`.